# Visualizing binary variable as count variable with time on x-axis, R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to make a line- or scatter plot (preferable ggplot) which has time on the x-axis and a count of 1's in a binary variable on the y-axis. This is my data. Can anyone help me?

```
tweet_id    text                date          morality_binary
1           Lorem ipsum...      2014-01-01    1
2           Lorem ipsum...      2015-01-01    0
3           Lorem ipsum...      2016-01-01    1
4           Lorem ipsum...      2017-01-01    0
5           Lorem ipsum...      2018-01-01    0
6           Lorem ipsum...      2019-01-01    1
```

Here's a reproducible example of the actual data:

```
df <- structure(list(X.1 = 0:5, X = c(502026L, 198322L, 711188L, 563672L, 
993641L, 474508L), tweet_id = c(867481042428579840, 469268704732393536, 
915248573083553792, 689948979740725248, 1003463365811953664, 
958533305716101120), user_username = c("GerryConnolly", "SenatorMenendez", 
"RepJayapal", "RoyBlunt", "SenJeffMerkley", "RepChrisStewart"
), text = c(".@governorva demonstrates compassion that potus lacks. trump's immigration eo still threatens to tear this family apart. #freeliliana", 
"hoy,repet<ed> mi llamado a mis colegas rep. de la c<e1>mara para q hagan lo correcto y aprueben una #reformamigraotira #cir", 
"@repadamsmith @reproybalallard the incarceration system for immigrants operates in the shadows, at a huge profit for corporations. our bill phases them out in 3 years.", 
"now isn't the time to accept syrian &amp; iraqi refugees into our country w/o proper system for vetting. rt if you agree", 
"mr. president, the only <93>horrible law<94> is your policy. you have the power to change it. if you saw what i saw today, you would. never before has america deliberately inflicted cruelty on children to deter asylum seekers from finding refuge here. never. and we never should.", 
"republicans and democrats need to work together and reform our immigration policies. #sotu"
), created_at = c("2017-05-24", "2014-05-22", "2017-10-03", "2016-01-20", 
"2018-06-04", "2018-01-31"), user_name = c("Rep. Gerry Connolly", 
"Senator Bob Menendez", "Rep. Pramila Jayapal", "Senator Roy Blunt", 
"Senator Jeff Merkley", "Rep. Chris Stewart"), user_verified = c("True", 
"True", "True", "True", "True", "True"), morality_binary = c(0.78794396, 
0.06992793, 0.75065666, 0.7655833, 0.85510856, 0.52538866), morality = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and this is what I want to get to
[image: final plot in my dreams]

Comment: What is your grouping variable? Is it text? Or date? Hard to tell with the data you have provided. Or are you just asking a straight forward line plot for date vs mortality_binary?

Comment: I have added a reproducible sample of the df. But yes, just a straight forward line-plot

Comment: This one does not do the job ```ggplot(df, aes(x = created_at, y = morality)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Date",
    y = "moralizing text")```

Comment: Can clarify by what you mean by your code not working? Your `created_at` on the data frame is a character vector. `ggplot(df, aes(x = as.Date(created_at), y = morality)) +   geom_point() +   labs(x = "Date",     y = "moralizing text")` will provide a more accurate x-axis.

Comment: Again, if you want to count (assume that it's a sum of a group), then you have to provide a grouping element. The six lines of data you provided in the example doesnt give any hint of the grouping you intended.

Comment: I'm probably not expressing myself clear enough. I want something similar to this https://imgur.com/a/FwnVPfh

Comment: So in reality, I only want to count the 1's of morality as a function of time

Comment: try [cumsum](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cumsum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `summarise` the number of 1s in `morality`, then use that to plot with `ggplot2`. You can group by each date to summarise.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(created_at = as.Date(created_at)) %>%
  group_by(created_at) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(morality, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = created_at, y = count)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "moralizing text")
```

[image]

Or if you want to get the count for each year, then you can extract the year from the date, then summarise.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.numeric(format(as.Date(created_at),"%Y"))) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(morality, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = count)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "moralizing text")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm aiming for something like this: https://imgur.com/a/FwnVPfh don't know if it's even possible

Comment: So in reality, I only want to count the 1's of morality as a function of time